# Spock - Ignoring a data driven entry

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spock

Say I have the sample data driven spec:

```
class DataDriven extends Specification {
     def "maximum of two numbers"() {
         expect:
         Math.max(a, b) == c

         where:
         [a,b,c] << runSomeSQL()
     }
 }
```

Is there a way to tell Spock to officially ignore (as a contrived example) where `a < 7`?  EG as if I didn't use the data driven mechanism and simply `@Ignore`-ed the `a < 7` cases

Answer (score 3):

The only solution is to comment out the lines to be ignored.

Comment: Thanks Peter.. changed my example a bit

Comment: In that case, you'd have to filter the return value of `runSomeSql()` with a method such as `findAll`. There is no ignore mechanism for iterations of a data-driven tests.